# Build a hierarchical data structure to bind to treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-structures, treeview, kendo-ui

I need some help in building a windows filesystem into a treeview. I am not sure if I am getting this right. Below is the class I built. I need to be able to populate this from a root folder and convert the data into Json to be able to bind it to the treeview in the View.

```
    public class Folder
    {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<Folder> ChildFolders { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What TreeView are you using? Have you developed your own?

Comment: I am using kendoUI TreeView http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html

Comment: So, what's wrong with your Model? Why do you need to convert the data to Json? Do you want to add/remove nodes dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

1. First add a **parent** field like `public Folder Parent {get;set;}`

If we are talking about Web UI:

1. Use a `<ul> <li>` structure, and play with css like : **.tree > ul > li { //some padding }** and so on.
2. Write a recursive Html.Helper that will construct the nested list structure